# how do I split array element into more element

Tags: java, list, arraylist

this is my array:

```
[UserID|Name|Password|IC or Passport Number|Gender|Phone, 01234567|Bob|abcderf|MALE|01234567]
```

and I want to convert into:

```
[UserID|Name|Password|IC or Passport Number]
[01234567|Bob|abcderf|MALE|01234567]
```

this is my code: (but it doesn't work]

```
String[] arr = userList.toArray(new String[userList.size()]);
    String[] arrr = arr[0].split(",");
    for ( int i=0; i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
```

Comment: More to the point, how is that an array? Is that an array of strings? Is it a string? How do you decide where to split? In the middle? Please include some detail on what we're dealing with and what you expect as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use method from Arrays if lenght of array is always the same

```
    String[] array1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, 4); 
    String[] array2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 4, 9);
```